# Swift SpriteKit: iAd loading bug

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, iad

I currently have a bug with the app I am working on where when a user taps on an iAd banner and the ad loads, the game resets. By "resets" I mean all their progression (other than the NSUserDefaults data) is reset to 0 and the scene is reset back to the start of the game.

My game primary runs from **didMoveToView()** and **touchesBegan()**. In my **GameViewController** the game scene is built from **viewWillLayoutSubviews()**.

Here is how I control my ads and placement. Not sure if has to do with the placement of my code or the ad.

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import iAd

// Global Ad Variable
var adBanner: ADBannerView!

class GameViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {

/* Load Ads */
func loadAds() {
    adBanner = ADBannerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: view.bounds.size.height - 50, width: 320, height: 50))
    adBanner.delegate = self
    adBanner.hidden = true
    self.view.addSubview(adBanner)
}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {

    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView

        // Create and Configure the scene
        scene.size = skView.bounds.size

        skView.showsFPS = false // SHOW OR HIDE FRAMES PER SECOND
        skView.showsNodeCount = false

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }

}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    loadAds()
}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        return .AllButUpsideDown
    } else {
        return .All
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    adBanner.hidden = true
    print("There was an error loading ad")
}

func bannerViewWillLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    print("Ad Loading")
}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    adBanner.hidden = false
    print("Ad Loaded")
}
}
```

Comment: it looks like you are creating a new scene since viewWillLayoutSubviews is probably getting called on return from iAd.  BTW  apple is no longer accepting apps enrolled in iAd, so unless you plan on releasing your app in Sept if/when they announce something new,  I would not even use it, instead switch to a 3rd party service like adMob

Comment: Yeah, I did a little research online and found out that it is exactly as you say,  the scene is being called again when an ad loads. And also, thank you so much for letting me know about iAd. I had no idea they were implementing a change. Appreciate it!